# What is the total mechanical energy of the system?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring

I am having trouble working through the following question from my textbook and am searching for some help with solving this problem.

A mass of $1.30 kg$ is attached to a spring and the system is undergoing simple harmonic oscillations with a frequency of $2.10 Hz$ and an amplitude of $7.80\times10^{-2} m$. What is the total mechanical energy of the system?

My workings I have are, but they seem not to be correct,

The maximum amplitude, the potential energy stored in the spring will be the total mechanical energy of the system (because here $v=o$)

simple harmonic motion of spring says that 
$F = ma = - k x$

so,

$$w^2=\frac{k}{m}=(2\pi\times2.10Hz)^2$$
$$k=(2\pi\times2.10 Hz)^2\times1.30kg$$
$$k=226.33\frac{N}{m}$$

Then calculating the mechanical energy,

$$E_{mech}=\frac{1}{2}\times kA^2=\frac{1}{2}\times226.33 \frac{N}{m}\times(7.8m)^2$$
$$E_{mech}=6885J$$

However this answer doesn't seem to be correct, searching for some help, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the edit, would you be able to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you used the value 7.8m for the amplitude, but the amplitude in the question is $7.8 \times 10^{-2} m$.

Comment: so then $0.6885$J? do you use cm or m?

Comment: You should use meters because Joules is expressed as $\frac{kg\times m^2}{s^2}$